# Hows does SmartTarget sort results from multiple promotions?

Tags: smarttarget

I have a region which is targetted by multiple promotions, and a query for that region which returns items from more than one promotion. How does SmartTarget decide which order to sort the results?

Answer (score 5):

Great question!

From the user (Content Editor) perspective:

- The SmartTarget promotions are ordered in the order of how they appear in the Targetting tab in the Content Manager Explorer. The top promotion is shown first.
- Inside a ST promotion the items (component presentations) are ordered according how specified in the promotion, i.e. ordered by date

In more technical detail

- The SmartTarget API on the webapp queries Fredhopper
- Fredhopper returns an unordered list of ST promotions. Well, Fredhopper orders it, but ST ignores the order.
- Fredhopper does order de items ín the ST promotions
- SmartTarget orders the ST promotions

  - SmartTarget then reads the meta promotion (a technical promotion hidden from the end user.
  - That metadata specifies the order of the ST promotions
- When you create a ST promotion in the Targeting tab, or change the order of the promotions, then SmartTarget will change the Meta Promotion, specifiying the order of ST promtions